# Php While loop to load all the images from table

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a new website using HTML/PHP/MYSQL.

Now I have to load the content.php, which will show ALL the photos from 1 id into the webpage.
Problem is, each ID from table has DIFFERENT amount of photos (Could be many, like 30 photos...). So I need a while loop php script to load all the photos from 1 id.

-->Here is my TABLE name photo_details, you can see that each ID will has totally different amount of photo(s). (Onyl DEMO here, real table could be more than 5 or more photos.)

table*(*column*=*value*):

id=1, photo_1=banner1.jpg, photo_2=banner3.jpg, photo_3= (BLANK)

id=2, photo_1=banner2.jpg, photo_2= (BLANK),    photo_3=(BLANK)

id=3, photo_1=banner1.jpg, photo_2=banner2.jpg, photo_3=(BLANK)

(Sample of my PHP--->Content.php file)

```
include"storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

$dynamicBanner="";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo_details WHERE id='$id' ");
$productCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productCount>0){
```

**> WRITE A WHILE LOOP PHP SCRIPTS HERE TO LOAD ALL THE PHOTO FROM 1 TABLE ROW, until no more photos to be loaded.**
    }

`$dynamicBanner .=` *************

```
}
```

.......

BOTTOM:

```
 <div id="right_banner">
    <?php echo $dynamicBanner ?>
 </div>
```

Thank for anyone who help me to find the solution. I am very appreciate to it. =)

Comment: The manual perfectly describes the behaviour of functions such as [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) - what have you tried?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work for you its a slight modification to something similar i use to echo out a set amount of images.

```
$query = $db->query("select * from `photo_details` WHERE id='$id'");

$images = array();

while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $images[] = $row['image'];
}
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" />';
}
```